# Why does my server only respond once?

Tags: c#, server

I've been trying to write a basic client-server setup in C#, going mainly by [these](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y0e13d3(v=vs.110).aspx) tutorials, altering the code a bit for some extra functionality. The main difference I have introduced is control codes: strings interpreted by the server to change the behaviour of the response. Those are fine, all working.

I can get the server to respond - once. That's the problem: the client connects, is recognised by the server and can send a message, but the second message appears to not get through at all - the server doesn't notice it and the client freezes.

The server:

```
while (true)
            {
                Output.Log("Waiting for a connection...", LogType.Info);
                // Program is suspended while waiting for an incoming connection.
                Socket handler = listener.Accept();
                data = null;

                // Options
                bool echo = false;
                bool display = true;

                // An incoming connection needs to be processed.
                while (true)
                {
                    bytes = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                    string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                    data += message;

                    List<string> controlCodes = GetControlCodes(message);
                    if (controlCodes.Contains("Echo-Back"))
                    {
                        echo = true;
                    }
                    if (controlCodes.Contains("No-Display"))
                    {
                        display = false;
                    }

                    if (data.IndexOf("<End>") > -1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // Show the data on the console.
                if (display)
                {
                    Output.Log("Data received: " + data, LogType.Info);
                }
                else
                {
                    Output.Log("Data received, No-Display set", LogType.Info);
                }

                // Echo the data back to the client.
                byte[] msg;
                if (echo)
                {
                    msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
                }
                else
                {
                    msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<Received;No-Echo>");
                }

                Output.Log("Response sent: " + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(msg), LogType.Info);
                handler.Send(msg);
            }
```

And the client:

```
sender.Connect(remoteEP);
Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
    sender.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());

while (true)
{
    Console.Write("> ");
    string userMessage = Console.ReadLine();
    Send(sender, userMessage + "<End>");
}

// ...

public static void Send(Socket sender, string message)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

    int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

    int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
    Console.WriteLine("Response: {0}",
        Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));
}
```

The sockets, as far as I can tell, are fine, since I can get a connection for the first message.

On breaking the programs when the freeze occurs, the server is frozen on the `listener.Accept()` call, and the client on `sender.Receive()`. This sort of makes me think that it's because I haven't closed the previous connection; how and where do I do so? How, in essence, do I fix it so that both aren't waiting simultaneously?

Comment: You could hit the "break all" button to see where the client is "frozen".  Have you tried stepping through the code to see what it's actually doing?  Basic debugging?

Comment: @roryap Yes I have tried debugging it; I'm not quite that far gone yet... However, I didn't know there was a 'break all' button; care to point me to it?

Comment: It's the one that looks like a pause button, right between the "play" and "stop" buttons.

Comment: @roryap edited those details in

Comment: You should also `break;` if `bytesRec <= 0` (at server or client) - that is how a `Stream` indicates `EOF`